# adding pictures in certain places in a richtextbox in C#

Tags: c#, image, textbox, spell-checking

Alright,

Question #1: well i have a richtextbox, and id like to add emotions to it, so for instance, if ":)" was in the textbox, id want the picture of a smiley face in its place.

Question #2: i have a normal textbox, NOT a richtextbox, and id like to add some sort of spell check to it. that highlights the mis-spelt words as you type

~id like code examples if possible. thanks!

Comment: These are two distinct questions, please split into two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some third party spell checking components around that can be attached to normal text boxes.

Write yourself a checklist showing the few things you need to achieve with it then grab a trail version of a couple. Test them and buy the best one. ([Here's an example](http://www.dart.com/rsdesk.aspx))

Also check out http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/spellchecker_pp.aspx on CodeProject - this may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/csexrichtextbox.aspx) for the RichTextBox. You'll need to check the characters as users type them and replace them with the appropriate image.